# I downloaded the 4 dlc in Mass Effect 3, and now i cant find any players

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

When I played Mass Effect 3 on PS3 before, without the free dlcs I could always find other players online.

Then I saw a post in google about free dlcs and I downloaded them.

- Online pass
- Retaliaton
- Reckoning
- Resurgence
- Rebellion

But now I can't find any other players online anymore. I can play only solo.

I don't want to delete the dlcs because there are so many additional characters in them.

Comment: Hello Ambrose. I took the liberty of doing a little cleanup of your question. Unfortunately, it's still not enough information for us to help you. What DLCs exactly did you install? Right now, there are [6 free DLCs for ME3](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Downloadable_Content).

Comment: Online pass, Retaliaton, Reckoning, Resurgence, Rebellion. there

Comment: Oh another thing, are you playing on PC, Xbox or PS?

Comment: im playing on ps3

Answer (score 3):

There are actually 5 free DLCs for multiplayer; you seem to have missed the "Earth" DLC. I assume most people aware of free DLC have installed all of them.

The easiest way to get all of them is to install the [Multiplayer Collection](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3:_Multiplayer_Collection), which includes

- Resurgence
- Rebellion
- Earth
- Retaliation
- Reckoning

Comment: And to answer the question, you won't see anyone online unless you have all 5 of these DLCs installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you download any multiplayer DLC, you should download ALL the multiplayer DLC.  The reason is, that the game will only match you with players with the same combination of DLC.

If you have no multiplayer DLC, you'll be matched with other players that have not yet installed DLC.

If you have all the multiplayer DLC, you'll be matched with the general multiplayer community.

If you have any other combination of DLC, you'll be extremely lucky to find any matches at all.